# Find the fitting values of unknown parametres by ParametricNDSolveValue

Tags: differential-equations, parametric-functions

I have this ODE:

`eq = E^(2 a x[t]) + (2 + 13 E^(2 (a - b) x[t]) x'[t]^2==  6 a E^(2 (a - b) x[t]) ((2 a - b) x'[t]^2+ x''[t] )`

I want to solve for `x[t]`, while `a` and `b` are unknown parameters.

I try to know the values of `a` and `b` by knowing previously that
`x[t] = Log [1+0.75 t^2 ]`

So what I did is using `ParametricNDSolveValue`:

`ParametricNDSolveValue[{eq, x[0] == 0,x'[0] == 0}, x, {t, 0, 1}, {a, b}]`

Then I tried to find any near values for `a` and `b` that fit `x[t]` analytic formula

`Show[Plot[{Log[1 + 0.75 t^2], Evaluate[(sol[a, b][t]) /. {a -> 1, b -> 2}]}, {t, 0, 2}]]`

which gives:

[image]

Also I tried:

`Show[Plot[{Log[1 + 0.75 t^2], Evaluate[Table[sol[a, -1][t], {a, 0.5, 1.5, 0.1}]]}, {t, 0, 2}, PlotRange -> {Automatic, {0, 1}}]]`

which gives:

[image]

Still the curve of `x[t]` far away from the numeric solution. Any help how to scan over `a` and `b` and find the right values that make the numeric solution fits the analytic function ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was an error in your equation (missing parenthesis on the lhs), but I was able to fix it by running your code and comparing plots.

```
eq = E^(2 a x[t]) + (2 + 13 E^(2 (a - b) x[t])) x'[t]^2 ==  6 a E^(2 (a - b) x[t]) ((2 a - b) x'[t]^2+ x''[t] )
```

Also, if you want to do plots up to t=2, you should use that in ParametricNDSolve; you had the upper limit set to t=1.

```
sol=ParametricNDSolveValue[{eq, x[0] == 0,x'[0] == 0}, x, {t, 0, 2}, {a, b}]
```

I set up a "chi-square" type function, with some arbitrary granularity of .1 for a sum over time steps, and used NMinimize to vary {a,b} to find the smallest sum (best fit).  As you can see, ParametricNDSolve is struggling.

```
min= NMinimize[Sum[(Log[1 + 0.75 t^2]-sol[a,b][t])^2,{t,0,2,.1}],{a,b}]

During evaluation of In[15]:= ParametricNDSolveValue::ndsz: At t == 1.474181958097713`, step size is effectively zero; singularity or stiff system suspected.

During evaluation of In[15]:= InterpolatingFunction::dmval: Input value {1.5} lies outside the range of data in the interpolating function. Extrapolation will be used.

During evaluation of In[15]:= InterpolatingFunction::dmval: Input value {1.6} lies outside the range of data in the interpolating function. Extrapolation will be used.

During evaluation of In[15]:= InterpolatingFunction::dmval: Input value {1.7} lies outside the range of data in the interpolating function. Extrapolation will be used.

During evaluation of In[15]:= General::stop: Further output of InterpolatingFunction::dmval will be suppressed during this calculation.

During evaluation of In[15]:= ParametricNDSolveValue::ndsz: At t == 0.368708003383665`, step size is effectively zero; singularity or stiff system suspected.

During evaluation of In[15]:= ParametricNDSolveValue::ndsz: At t == 1.2893152654144109`, step size is effectively zero; singularity or stiff system suspected.

During evaluation of In[15]:= General::stop: Further output of ParametricNDSolveValue::ndsz will be suppressed during this calculation.

Out[15]= {1.17426, {a -> 0.222374, b -> -7.49302}}
```

You obtain a result, however looking at a plot, it doesn't look great.

```
Show[Plot[{Log[1 + 0.75 t^2], Evaluate[(sol[a, b][t]) /. nmin[[2]]]}, {t, 0, 2}]]
```

[image: \compare expect to obtained result]

But at least you have a starting point for what you're attempting to do.

Although NMinimize can speed up your guess-timation for the optimal {a,b} values, it looks like the results you were getting before show a similar behavior, so the main problem may lie in an earlier step; i.e. the solutions you're getting from ParametricNDSolve just aren't a close match.